# (Ruby on Rails) How To Improve A Rake Task Which Automatically Generates Posts For A Blog?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

I'm making a blog-like application & I currently have a rake task which automatically generates a new post every day if the current day is past the start date of a user. I want to improve it so that if a new user signs up for an account and selects a start date in the past, say a month ago, the rake task will auto generate all the posts for the previous month as well as continue its current function.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to implement this?

This is the code for the rake task:

```
namespace :abc do 
desc "Used to generate a new daily log"

task :create_post => :environment do

User.find_each do |currentUser|
 starting_date = currentUser.start_date

 Post.create!(content: "RAKED", user: currentUser, status: "new") if Date.today >= starting_date && Date.today.on_weekday?
end

puts "It worked yo"     
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [cron jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to `rake` the task. In `ruby`, you can use whenever `gem` that has a clear syntax for writing and deploying cron jobs. There is also [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby) about it. Let's try it.